# Name of fantasy film from the early 80s or late 70s with an elf and villain wearing metal helmet?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find the name of a fantasy film from the late 70s or early 80s. There was a hero, and there was an elf, and a villain who had a metal helmet with a patch over it that covered one eye. At the end of the film the helmet comes off to reveal the eye is burnt or scarred or missing (cant remember exactly which). I **think** that also at the end of the film it is revealed that the hero and the villain are related (brothers I think). I cannot remember any other details. Does anyone know the name of this film?

Comment: @Otis thanks for finding all these dupes!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's [Hawk the Slayer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080846/combined):

[image]

The villain in question is played by Jack Palance. It has, ahem, not aged well.

Comment: Yes! That is the film!! Thanks it has been bugging me all day long!

Comment: Not aged well? NOT AGED WELL?!? Hawk's a classic, I tell you! King among the low-budget 80's fantasy movies!

Comment: BEASTMASTER FTW

Comment: @Omegacron But have you ever [punched a bloke in the face for saying _Hawk the Slayer_ is rubbish](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Spaced#Change_[2.2])?

Comment: @eshier - lol, no, I haven't had that opportunity yet. But I have definitely had those sorts of arguments with my friends. For instance, my best mate actually likes what Disney is doing with the Star Wars franchise...